# Xcode Data Protection

Tags: ios, xcode5, data-protection

Ever since the release of Xcode 5.0, there has been a new edition of the `Capabilities` tab in the target settings of an Xcode project. It includes the ability to configure the entitlements on your projects App ID. One of the capabilities is `Data Protection`. Enabling the setting in the target settings does no more than just:

> Add the "Data Protection" entitlement to your App ID

How do I actually implement Data Protection in my application? What are the applications of Data Protection? Does it encrypt all my application data?

Comment: It seems that setting was to support newer devices which were having hardware encryption and then we have to explicitly give the dataProtection level to files which we are creating in our application. In one of my application i  didn't even enable data protection and just created my file with DataProtection options and it was protected when device was locked.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in 's documentation on the subject: [Enabling Data Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW30).

> Data protection adds a level of security to files stored on disk by your app. Data protection uses the built-in encryption hardware present on specific devices to store files in an encrypted format on disk.

This means that the data stored will automatically be encrypted.